# Reference is useless in std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, bind, placeholder

```
//example

void f(int &n1, int& n2)
{
    n1++;
    n2++;
}
int main()
{
    int n1 = 1, n2 = 2;
    auto bound1 = std::bind(&f, n1, std::ref(n2));
    bound1();    // 1 3
    std::cout << n1  << n2 << endl;
    auto bound2 = std::bind(&f, std::placeholders::_1, std::ref(n2)); // 2 4
    bound2(n1);
    std::cout << n1  << n2 << endl;
}
```

My first question would be about the reference in function `f`, is it wrong to do `std::bind` on a function that receives a parameter by reference ?

Because in the code presented above the value of `n1` does not change. After all i see if i put `std::placeHolders::_1` value of `n1` will be change. That is my second question `std::placeHolders` call `std::ref` ?

I know the title is not really suggestive...

Comment: `n1` is copied in the call to `std::bind`.

Comment: Trying to understand your current understanding: why did you use `std::ref` for `n2`?

Comment: Note: personally I'd almost always prefer a lambda over `std::bind`.

Comment: In case my earlier comment needs more explanation: The answer to your questions seems to be that `std::bind` takes its arguments by value unless something special is done (e.g. using `std::ref`). The expression `std::bind(&f, n1, std::ref(n2));` looks like an example concocted specifically to demonstrate that `std::bind` takes its parameters by value unless something special is done (e.g. using `std::ref`). So... how did you come up with this example without knowing what it demonstrates? Did I miss something important from the question?

Answer (score 2):

> is it wrong to do std::bind on a function that receives a parameter by reference ?

No, it is not wrong.

Bound arguments are always stored by value. Therefore, a reference wrapper must be used if you want the bound argument to refer to an external object.

> That is my second question std::placeHolders call std::ref ?

The argument passed to the bound function are forwarded directly without being stored by value. As such, no reference wrapper is needed.

Answer (score 2):

> is it wrong to do std::bind on a function that receives a parameter by reference ?

It is legal... but as you noted `n1` is unchanged which might be surprising.

Difference is more easy to spot with lambda IMO:

`[n1, &n2](){ f(n1, n2); }` versus `[&n1, &n2](){ f(n1, n2); }`

> That is my second question std::placeHolders call std::ref ?

No, but `bind` has to handle both `placeholder` types and `reference_wrapper` types especially.

Answer (score 0):

It's as you say.

Unless you use `std::ref`/`std::cref`, or a `std::placeholder`, your argument is copied.

The "stored" argument is then passed by reference to the function during invocation, but that won't impact the object you passed in at the callsite.

This may be surprising; you just have to get used to it.

You can derive it from the standard wording ([in `[func.bind.bind]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.bind.bind#1.7)) but honestly that whole section is pretty esoteric.

The same is true of `std::thread` — you must use `std::ref` if you want to carry references all the way through.

Both `std::thread` and `std::bind` usually execute the referred-to function "later", i.e. out of the current scope (your example for `std::bind` is unusual; you'd usually just call `f` directly there), so it's safer to make it so you have to *explicitly* say "take a reference to this thing if you want that. That may or may not have been the rationale of the designers.